# custom post with loading script per single post

Tags: functions, customization, javascript, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

I read many Q&As here on SO...(and elsewhere but they don't count...lol)
I think I follow the rules of WP.org but still it does not load the scripts.

Scenario:
Custom template for post in Php:

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: YYY
 * Description: Form for YYY donation. 
 * NO FOOTER
 */
get_header(); ?>
<div id="content-yyy">
```

theme *functions.php*

```
function donate_adding_scripts() {
    wp_register_script('donateParsleyJs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/parsley.min.js', array('jquery'),'1.11.1');
    wp_enqueue_script('donateParsleyJs');
    wp_register_script('donateParsleyHeJs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/he.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('donateParsleyHeJs');
    wp_register_script('donateJs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/donateJs.js', array('jquery'),'1.11.1', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('donateJs');
}

function donate_adding_styles() {
    wp_register_script('donateStyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/donateStyle.css');
    wp_enqueue_script('donateStyle');
}

function loadDonateScripts() {
   if (is_single()) {
       global $post;
       if($post->ID=="8436"){ // only for post Id = 8436
            add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'donate_adding_scripts' );  
            add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'donate_adding_styles' );  
       }
   }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'loadDonateScripts');
```

As I am using a *setLocal* for *parsleyjs* I have

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.ParsleyValidator.setLocale('he');
</script>
```

I have several issues:

1. the addition to *functions.php* does not load the CSS
2. the JS scripts only load if I add `$in_footer=true` to functions.php file and `get_footer();` to the php template
3. All that said I wish to load these only for the specific custom post (ID=8436) hence `function loadDonateScripts()`

I wish to have the scripts loaded(obviously...duh), preferably in the footer...
Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

What if you completely remove the `loadDonateScripts` function and just add the conditional before enqueuing the scripts like in the the following:

```
function donate_adding_scripts() {
   if (is_single()) {
     global $post;
     if($post->ID=="8436"){ // only for post Id = 8436
        wp_register_script('donateParsleyJs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/parsley.min.js', array('jquery'),'1.11.1');
        wp_enqueue_script('donateParsleyJs');
        wp_register_script('donateParsleyHeJs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/he.js');
        wp_enqueue_script('donateParsleyHeJs');
        wp_register_script('donateJs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/donateJs.js', array('jquery'),'1.11.1', true);
        wp_enqueue_script('donateJs');
    }
  }
}

function donate_adding_styles() {
   if (is_single()) {
     global $post;
       if($post->ID=="8436"){ // only for post Id = 8436
          wp_register_script('donateStyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/donateStyle.css');
          wp_enqueue_script('donateStyle');
       }
    }
}


add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'donate_adding_scripts');
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'donate_adding_styles');
```

Comment: @czersplalce: its working; CSS is loading fine but no JSs...

Comment: error with CSS was: wp_register_style - !script;

Comment: Oops I didn't even notice that. Do you see any errors in your browser console?

Comment: the only thing there is the error for trying to set the locale: TypeError: Cannot read property 'setLocale' of undefined yielded by the lack of the scripts

Comment: I think its got something to do with: get_template_directory_uri()....not getting the currect path

Comment: Is your theme a child theme?

Comment: I just figured it is...a Twenty Eleven child probably

Comment: still for CSS get_template_directory_uri() does get to the root folder of the theme!?!?!

Comment: guess I did not pay attention but it seems that the part: if (is_single()) {
     global $post;
       if($post->ID=="8436"){ ---- does not enable the scripts...its not the call to get_template_directory_uri() IMO

Comment: after some debugging I found out that:  if (is_single('8436')) { OR VARIATION:
   global $post;
   if($post->ID=='8436')....does not pass, nor does the is_single function work in functions.php file!

Answer (score 0):

To all of you struggling to get custom scripts running from functions.php, here's how:

- ***WP v4.1.2***
- Th post is a ***custom template post***
- I needed to load 3 JSs - ***parsleyjs.js, he.js (i18n), custom_JsScript.js***
- I also wanted to have the ***CSS on a separate file***
- Only load these for ***a specific post***

  ```
  function donate_adding_scripts() {
  if (is_singular()) {
    global $post;
    if($post->ID=='8436'){ // only for post Id = 8436
          wp_register_script('donateParsleyHeJs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/he.js');
          wp_enqueue_script('donateParsleyHeJs');
          wp_register_script('donateParsleyJs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/parsley.min.js', array('jquery'),'1.11.1');
          wp_enqueue_script('donateParsleyJs');
          wp_register_script('donateJs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/donateJs.js', array('jquery'),'1.11.1');
          wp_enqueue_script('donateJs');
        }
      }
  }

  function donate_adding_styles() {
      if (is_singular()) {
        global $post;
        if($post->ID=='8436'){  // only for post Id = 8436
              wp_register_style('donateStyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/donateStyle.css');
          wp_enqueue_style('donateStyle');
        }
      }
  }
  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'donate_adding_scripts' );  
  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'donate_adding_styles' );
  ```

**ATTENTION:** (after carefully checking other options)

- it only worx with `is_singular()` - !`is_single()`
- the conditional `if($post->ID=='34')` only worx inside these functions & not as I tried at first inside `function loadDonateScripts()`
- styles need `wp_register_style` & `wp_enqueue_style` - **NOT** `wp_enqueue_script` & `wp_register_script` as some posts might mention!!!
- `add_action` must be called on the functions adding the scripts themselves and NOT on the function calling them (eg. `function loadDonateScripts()`)
- using `get_template_directory_uri()` while registering the scipts worx fine for both JS & CSS as long as you have the correct path

If you need to check paths, setup a custom post:

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: GetPath
 * Description: checking for current theme path. 
 */
    global $post;
    print_r($post->ID);
    print_r('<br />');
    print_r( get_stylesheet_directory_uri());
    print_r('<br />');
    print_r( get_template_directory_uri());
```

Create a new page with `Page Template - GetPath` in preview mode and just open it in your browser:

```
http://YOURWEBSITE_URL/?page_id=####&preview=true
```

You will get:

```
#### *(post ID num)
http://YOURWEBSITE_URL/wp-content/themes/YOUR_THEME_FOLDER_NAME
http://YOURWEBSITE_URL/wp-content/themes/YOUR_THEME_FOLDER_NAME
```